# Modifying XSL for multi lookup field

Tags: lookup-column, xslt, spfield

I'm trying to create custom XSLT for a multi lookup field, based on [this](http://sympmarc.com/2009/06/11/displaying-a-multi-select-column-nicely/) article.
When changing `disable-output-escaping` to `yes` I can see the html I want to modyify:

```
<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('http://...', RefreshPage); return false;"
href="http:/...">
7</a>
<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('...', RefreshPage); return false;"
href="http:/...">
17</a>
```

Now what I want to achieve, is:

1) change the links text (7 and 17 are some field values from lookup list, they're not itemIDs on this list) to multiply the values by a value from another column (C) (I can access it, so probably would pass it as a parameter to template) 

2) split the displayed items with some charactrer, like '|'

So what I want to get after modifications would be (if C value = 2): `14 | 34` instead of `7; 17` which is normaly displayed in this mulitlookup column. Is it possible to modify the script I'm using to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have all the values as either properties (@columnname) or as parameters ($parameterOfColumnname) and use the XSLT method **sum()**.

```
<xsl:variable name="multiplyingValue">
    <xsl:value-of select="@multiplyingValue" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="firstNumber">
    <xsl:value-of select="@firstNumber" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="secondNumber">
    <xsl:value-of select="@secondNumber" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="$multiplyingValue != ''">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum($firstNumber * $multiplyingValue)" />
    |
    <xsl:value-of select="sum($secondNumber * $multiplyingValue)" />
</xsl:if>
```

I'm not 100% sure if **sum()** is needed. I've seen examples on this without using *sum()* but still doing the `<xsl:value-of select="value here * $multiplyingValue" />`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was quite busy with other stuff, i forgot about this one sorry. well unfortunately i'm not able to get the values yet, the way I try to get them now (just the ones from multilookup, so I don't think about $multiplyingValue yet) is to parse the value of the field (like 1;#7;#2:17). I managed to get something like this in a variable: `<ids><id>1</id><id>7</id><id>2</id><id>17</id></ids>` so I thought iterating through this and getting every second value would work, but I cant iterate with for-each though this.

Comment: I try: `<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($tokens)/ids/id">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>` but nothing gets displayed..any ideas? sorry for duble-comment btw